# What listener for Sencha touch seachfield submit

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

Sencha touch has the searchfield object. When I use this one and hook the submit event to it, it doesn't work. I seems it only works with the change event listener. I searched through the documentation but could not find the correct eventtype. Does anyone know what the correct eventtype for the listener is to capture a searchfield submit?

Answer (score 0):

Use the searchfield inside a Form Panel and the submit handler will work.